# Is it possible to change portrait after starting the game?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

We've started a co-op game of Divinity: Original Sin. However, one of us forgot to match the portrait with the actual face style of the corresponding character. That is, we currently walk around like this:

[image: characters and portraits]

We've tried clicking on just about every UI element, but might be missing this option. Or perhaps it's not possible. **Can you change your portrait after the game has already started?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a fair bit of playing, in your homestead, one of the Inner chambers (the second room you unlock) has a mirror that allows you to change the portrait, gender and physical appearance of either of the source hunters, just like during character creation, as many times you want.

Here's what the mirror looks like:

[image: mirror in homestead]

And this is the UI you get for changing your character:

[image: character creation]

Comment: Does this still apply in the Enhanced Edition that was just released? Thanks.

Comment: @TylerForsythe I wouldn't know myself as I don't have that edition, but I'd assume so since the mirror was actually part of the story IIRC.

Comment: @Jeroen Thanks. Enhanced Edition is free for everyone who owned the original, so you should have it somewhere now :-)

Comment: @TylerForsythe I just unlocked that room in the advanced edition. I can confirm that the mirror is still there and working.